# Angular Reactive Form Validation Not Working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I tried for Angular Reactive form and my code for
the component class is: [Component Class file](https://pastebin.com/Ujq7yDQb)

And my HTML code is: [HTML file](https://pastebin.com/7024R1Ki)

I get this error in console:

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined
    at new LoginComponent (login.component.ts:24)
```

I know this error is because of the line:

```
validEmail = {
    field: true,
    error: this.myForm.controls.email.invalid && this.myForm.controls.email.dirty
  };
```

Also if I attempt to comment and 'error:' ngClass object,
the condition:

```
!myForm.invalid
```

in login form submit button not working.

I am new to angular, the doc is kinda more general. So please help me how to fix it.
For your testing, use the semantic-UI library for viewing the HTML.

Comment: Can you post the code in the form of text?

Comment: For my Question quality, I put it in Pastebin.

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan, always you create a form in ngOnInit, it's usefull write the form like `<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm"...>`. These *ngIf avoid initial errors

Answer (score 0):

I think you access `myFrom` before initializing it. You didn't post your code in your question, but I guess you defined validEmail in your class level and in that time your form is not initialized yet

Comment: then how can I access it to set for a ngClass property? I declared it in the beginning so, can't it be accessed

Comment: do it in your html, and usually it controls by *ngIf, see  https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/reactive-forms-and-form-validation-with-angular-fdcbcf98e1e8

Comment: I understand what you say, but can't I do like what I did in my code. what if there goes a lot of styles? can't I do it as ngClass object in component class?

Comment: even if you do `myForm: FromGroup = new FormGroup({...})` and initialize the form, error will go away, but the way you are doing is not working, because you evaluate the value and set it at begining, for example your error is always `true`, there is no code to set that again, this is why you should not swim against the river flow

Comment: I did remove the validEmail object and added the object directly to the form.

Comment: I need to add a class to the div if the email is dirty and invalid. and I cannot do that.

Comment: please create stackblitz to be able help you better